# Draw lines and write text on animated GIF image using PHP

Tags: php, drawing, gif, gd, animated-gif

Hello lovely swarm intelligence!

I have some PHP code, which draws lines in form of a grid system to an image and afterwards, it also writes some text on this image. My code works as expected with static images like PNG or JPG/JPEG, when I use the respective PHP `imagecreatefrom*` and `image*` functions.

Following the adjusted and simplified (without a lot of try-catch, if-conditions and variables) code for GIF images:

```php
$gif_filepath = '/tmp/animated.gif';
$font_filepath = '/tmp/some-font.ttf';

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($gif_filepath);

$gd_image = imagecreatefromgif($gif_filepath);

$line_color = imagecolorallocatealpha($gd_image, 0, 0, 0, 80);

$spacing = 25;

// Draw vertical lines
for ($iw = 0; $iw < $width / $spacing; $iw++) {
    imageline($gd_image, $iw * $spacing, 0, $iw * $spacing, $width, $line_color);
}

// Draw horizontal lines
for ($ih = 0; $ih < $height / $spacing; $ih++) {
    imageline($gd_image, 0, $ih * $spacing, $width, $ih * $spacing, $line_color);
}

$font_color = imagecolorallocate($gd_image, 255, 0, 0);

// Write text
imagefttext($gd_image,
    25,
    0,
    30,
    60,
    $font_color,
    $font_filepath,
    'Let\'s ask Stackoverflow!'
);

imagegif($gd_image);
```

PHP properly adds the respective lines and text to the GIF, but at the end it's only returning a single (probably the first) frame of the entire GIF.

Is it possible with PHP (in best case without any third-party libraries / tools) to draw these lines and write the text on the animated GIF image, so that it is afterwards still animated or is this technically not supported / possible?

I've seen, that there is a PHP function [`imagecopymerge`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagecopymerge.php), but I wasn't able to archive my target with this function.

Comment: Maybe you already realise this, but it's not really true that "it's not really a GIF anymore afterwards" - GIF is just a file format, which can represent still images as well as animated ones; it's just that other formats have become more common for still images. So your real question becomes how to edit *frames of an animated image*.

Comment: Good point. I'll adjust my question a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like as it's technically not possible to solve this with PHP native functions.

However, using [`shell_exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) and [`ffmpeg`](https://ffmpeg.org/) it can be archived in PHP:

```php
$gif_filepath = '/tmp/animated.gif';
$target_image_filepath = '/tmp/modified_animated.gif';
$font_filepath = '/tmp/some-font.ttf';

$spacing = 25;

# Draw grid system (horizontal + vertical lines)
shell_exec("ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -nostdin -y -i $gif_filepath -vf 'drawgrid=width=$spacing:height=$spacing:thickness=1:color=black@0.8' $target_image_filepath 2>&1");

# Write text
shell_exec("ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -nostdin -y -i $gif_filepath -vf \"drawtext=text='Let\'s ask Stackoverflow!':fontsize=25:x=30:y=60:fontcolor=red:fontfile=$font_filepath\" $target_image_filepath 2>&1");

// $target_image_filepath now contains the grid system and respective text
```

There also exists a third-party [PHP library PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg), which maybe can be used instead of `shell_exec()`, if it supports the respective filters for GIF files.